# How to backup a Pritunl Client profile?

Tags: openvpn

I am using Pritunl Client on one computer and would like to backup the profile in order to import it on a second computer. I have tried copying the .ovpn and .conf files in my home/.config/pritunl/profiles directory to the second computer.

When I import the .conf file in Pritunl Client on the second OS X computer, I get the following error when trying to connect:

```
Failed to get key from keychain (security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain. )
```

When importing the .ovpn file and trying to connect, it asks for my username and password (but not the OTP key or PIN). I get an error saying "Failed to authenticate."

How can I export and then import my Pritunl profile in order to configure Pritunl on a second computer?

Comment: The following discussion basically says to reimport the profile, which I have tried multiple times. https://docs.pritunl.com/discuss/5b5eb0beefd5c600032216c5

Comment: This discussion has no resolution either: https://docs.pritunl.com/discuss/5cae6431a8019b001bececa8

Comment: Tunnelblick seems to import the .ovpn file correctly: https://tunnelblick.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

To use pritunl profile in another computer:

1. Copy desired profile from pritunl/profiles directory.
2. Search "pritunl" in Keychain Access app and open it to see account, password and etc.
3. Then Create one item like as that in Keychain Access app of destination computer.
4. Now open Pritunl app and you can see the profile and connect to it :)

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was to install [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/) and then import the .ovpn file.